# Refresh Data Locally on Server database changes

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

how to refresh local data automatically when server data changes in azure mobile app(android).Right now i m using a timer that refresh my server request but this approach is not satisfactory as my app keep on sending requests to azure.What is the best approach for doing this?I also tried to understand one of the answer in stack overflow based on Exponential Back Off Delay Based but failed to understand.Kindly just guide me on this

Comment: Is your main question how the be notified of changes in the database, or is it on how to get changed data pushed to the client app?

Comment: sorry for confusion it is how to get changed data pushed to the client app?

Comment: It depends on other factors too. A targeted push notification could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

For communicating server-side updates to client apps, use [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr).

Here's some guidance on using it with Azure Mobile Apps: [Real-time with ASP.NET SignalR and Azure Mobile .NET Backend](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/05/30/real-time-with-asp-net-signalr-and-azure-mobile-net-backend/)

> We just released an update for Azure Mobile Services .NET backend which enables you to use ASP.NET SignalR for real-time, bi-directional communications with your mobile applications. SignalR will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and fallback to other “techniques” (i.e. HTTP hacks ) when it isn't. Regardless of the mode, your application code stays the same.

Comment: I would add that the app service needs WebSockets turned on in the settings in the Azure portal (or at least, it did when I last looked), if you want to take advantage of websockets. SignalR doesn't need it but may default to polling under the covers, if a websockets channel is not available.

Comment: Okay let me try